# Bot cannot return Username from IDs which are below certain number

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

This is just sheet which links ingame characters with their discord accounts. I use thhis method to return IDs.

[image: List of ID-username sheet]

```
public static List<String> idsToUsernames(List<String> ids){

        ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String id : ids) {
            try {
                usernames.add(bot.retrieveUserById(id).complete().getAsTag());
            }catch (ErrorResponseException e){
                usernames.add("User is unknown");
            }
        }

        return usernames;
    }
```

I am just very curious about it. Was there any update which affected this?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the error instead of ignoring it?

Comment: I just left try-catch there if someone tries to link unexisting id. I will, thanks

Comment: The error is:
`Exception in thread "Timer-0" net.dv8tion.jda.api.exceptions.ErrorResponseException: 10013: Unknown User`
What should I do with it?